# MapProxy WMS Print Scale Problem

Tags: geoserver, scale, resolution, mapproxy, dpi

The application that I work with consumes WMS services created in Geoserver via MapProxy. I used ysld to style my layers. As long as I want just display my layers in the application, the scales that I configured via ysld are preserved. When I print the same WMS service scales change. 
I found in the MapProxy documentation (Scale vs. resolution: https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.9.0/configuration.html?highlight=scale) that the scales are changing depending on dpi. The one that I use is 300. Is there any way to keep MapProxy from changing the scale? 
Here is an example of my ysld style that looks different if it's displayed or printed.

```
feature-styles:

- name: Ortsname
  rules:
  - name: Ortsname (1:2000 - 1:9500)
    scale: [2000,9499]
    symbolizers:
    - text:
        label: ${name}
        fill-color: '#000000'
        font-family: Arial
        font-size: 12
        font-style: normal
        font-weight: normal
        placement: point
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the MapProxy documentation in the link, there's a [utility available to work out scales for you](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.9.0/mapproxy_util.html#mapproxy-util-scales).

It's a subcommand for the **mapproxy-util** command line tool, you can include dpi as an input, and it can optionally create the YAML containing the scale values which can paste into your mapproxy configuration file as a grid.

Tweaking the example from the documentation

```
mapproxy-util scales --dpi 300 --as-res-config 100000 50000 25000 10000
```

It's been a while since I used mapproxy but i imagine you can set up two grids, one configured for each resolution, and have the client choose the print version of the grid prior to printing?